# "gulp" command not recognized after installation

Tags: node.js, windows, gulp

I'm installing gulp following [this method](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/).

i install gulp using `npm install --global gulp-cli`. after installation is complete, I run `gulp -v` and this error appears:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing gulp both locally inside the project and globally as well. Try below 2 commands

```
npm install gulp
npm install -g gulp
```